# Heroku tries to load resources from https:// instead of http:// on my custom domain - how can i fix this?

Tags: ssl, heroku

On my custom domain (free dyno, no SSL) it's trying to load resources (stylesheet, etc.) from HTTPS which is obviously failing and giving me GET https://mycustomdomain/img/favicon.ico net::ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT (and so on) error...

Any ideas? All my googling has failed, and similar questions have no working solutions either.
[please check console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdx3f.png)

Comment: Visit your website with `http://` instead of `https://` if that did not resolve your issue it means in your code you are referencing `https://` explicitely.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that, too. It still loads from https for some weird reason?! I wanna find where is it explicitly specifying https:// ... i guess it's connected to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error just now when I was deploying a Ruby on Rails app that I was upgrading to a newer version. I set `config.force-ssl = true` which is what I normally do for Heroku production websites. However this one is a free dyno website that only I use which doesn't include SSL. SSL is only allowed with paid dynos.

I decided to check the Heroku settings and saw that it created a custom domain record for the Heroku default domain name with a DNS target. I deleted the custom domain record. I commented out the `config.force-ssl = true` statement in my rails app and deployed the changes to Heroku. That got rid of the error.